# Fetch all attachments from a mail using java mail iteratively

Tags: java, email, recursion, email-attachments, mime

Below is the recursive approach which I can use to fetch all attachments from a mail.

```
public List<InputStream> getAttachments(Message message) throws Exception {
        Object content = message.getContent();
        if (content instanceof String)
            return null;        

        if (content instanceof Multipart) {
            Multipart multipart = (Multipart) content;
            List<InputStream> result = new ArrayList<InputStream>();

            for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
                result.addAll(getAttachments(multipart.getBodyPart(i)));
            }
            return result;

        }
        return null;
    }

    private List<InputStream> getAttachments(BodyPart part) throws Exception {
        List<InputStream> result = new ArrayList<InputStream>();
        Object content = part.getContent();
        if (content instanceof InputStream || content instanceof String) {
            if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition()) || StringUtils.isNotBlank(part.getFileName())) {
                result.add(part.getInputStream());
                return result;
            } else {
                return new ArrayList<InputStream>();
            }
        }

        if (content instanceof Multipart) {
                Multipart multipart = (Multipart) content;
                for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
                    BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
                    result.addAll(getAttachments(bodyPart));
         }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Can this be achieved without recursion by simply using iteration as recursion consumes a considerable amount of space in stack ?

Comment: Short answer:  yes, because anything that can be done recursively can also be done iteratively.

Comment: @Makoto How do I get it done in this case? Because I find it to be never ending if it is modelled iteratively

Comment: Do you actually understand this code? If so, what part seems to be difficult to implement in iterative scenario?

Comment: If you have already attempted to write your version and ran into a problem, you will be much better off sharing with us both your code and the exact difficulty you encountered.

Comment: @PM77-1 Ofcourse I do understand the code. I am running into difficulty thinking about the case where there are iterations of the pattern numerous times like multipart inside bodypart